# Using both leaflet's wms and extend on same script?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a main application which switches between multiple satellite options. Now the main application initially has all its options initialized using .`wms` like the code below:

```
              var satelitteLayer1 = L.tileLayer.wms(url,{
                   service: 'WMS'
                   //The rest of the header parameters
              });
```

now my challenge is there is another satellite API I would like to integrate but doesn't use .`wms` like above but .`extend`... When I add it to the same script I get an error message saying Map container already initialized, when I try adding it to the same as above I get an error message saying error authenticating although I did declare the key, id and authorization parameters. One of the tech guys from the company sent an example code which is instantiated like below:

```
             L.TileLayer.SecureLayer = L.TileLayer.extend({
                 createTile: function(coords,done){
                    //Logic of the function
                 }
             })
```

I am new in terms of using leaflet and would like to know if there a way to use both `wms` and `extend` on the same script since I see the approach is different? Or if anyone can actually explain the differences between .`wms` and .`extend` in layman's terms so that I can know which route to take in solving this...

Comment: Thanks for the response... So with leaflet... when declaring the wmsLayer is there a way to send headers as I just found out the api will only take authentication via headers.... as it is using a GET request

Answer (score 0):

```
    /*********WMS***********/   
var wmsLayer = L.tileLayer.wms('http://127.0.0.1:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?', {
    layers: 'test:gj'
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... So with leaflet... when declaring the wmsLayer is there a way to send headers as I just found out the api will only take authentication via headers.... as it is using a GET request